# How to fix calling index in event handler returning NaN in react?

Tags: reactjs, indexing

When calling index for the event handler handleRemoveItem(event), the index of the span tag returns NaN when trying to parseInt(event.target.id)

I'm trying to create a simple ReactJS program that will populate div's with user entered data, and then can be deleted by clicking on the div

The following code is a component that is exported to the index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class DivList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = { text: "", filter: "", data: [] };
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    let text = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ text });
  }

  clearTheArray = () => {
    this.setState({ data: [] });
  };

  handleButtonClick(event) {
    if (this.state.text.length > 0) {
      let data = this.state.data.slice();
      data.push(this.state.text);
      let text = "";
      // TODO: Update state with data and text
      this.setState({ text });
      this.setState({ data });
    }
  }

  handleRemoveItem(event) {
    let newIndex = parseInt(event.target.id, 10);
    console.log(event.target.id + " is the actual index");
    let dataCopy = this.state.data.slice();
    console.log(newIndex + " is the index");
    dataCopy.splice(newIndex, 1);
    this.setState({ data: dataCopy });
  }


  render() {
    let data = this.state.data.slice();
    let list = data.sort().map((elem, index) => (
      <span onClick={this.handleRemoveItem.bind(this)} id={index}>
        {" "}
        <div key={index}> {elem} </div>{" "}
      </span>
    ));
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Dynamic Div</h1>
        <h2>Sort and filter</h2>
        Enter text:&nbsp;
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e)}
        />
        &nbsp;
        {/*console.log(data) */}
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)}>Add</button>
        &nbsp;
        <button type="button" onClick={this.clearTheArray}>
          {" "}
          Reset{" "}
        </button>
        <br />
        {list}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I expect to be able to click on a  element on the page, and see it get deleted. 
However, the first  element gets deleted when I click any of the  elements, instead of the one I clicked. I believe this is a problem with my indexing but I can't figure out what's causing it

Comment: Firstly, have you checked `event.target.id` is the value you think it is? Secondly, you need to identify elements in an array with a key, and if the list is going to change, then those keys can't be the array index because that will cause issues. It needs to be a unique identifier of that element. Also, `.map` already returns a new array so you don't have to `.slice()` the data first

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like event.target.id is the value I want. It should be the index but when i console.log to check it, I continuously get "NaN". How would I rewrite this to get the index of the id from the span element?